# ¿que me falta para que se conecta el delphi embarcadero 10.3 con mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, delphi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice una tablitas en SQL, ya saque mi *script* y me instale el *MySQL Connector ODBC*, ese instale en 64 bits (porque mi laptop es de 64bits), luego fui al panel de control/herramientas administrativas/orígenes de datos OBDC(64bits) y agregué la conexión.

Hice lo mismo que en [este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KS-dy0_lQpU), pero al momento de conectar con la base de datos desde el Embarcadero, al elegir el catálogo de la base de datos, me aparece en pantalla el mensaje de la imagen de arriba:

> [Administrador de controladores ODBC] **La arquitectura del DSN especificado no coincide entre el controlador y la aplicación**.

Ayuda por favor, o tal vez otro método para conectar Delphi y MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

El IDE de Delphi, al menos hasta la versión 10.4 **es una aplicación de 32 bits**, y por tanto las DLL's que cargue en memoria deben ser también de 32 bits.

Esto es relevante porque quieres conectarte en tiempo de diseño, así que aunque tu sistema operativo sea de 64 bits, para conectarte debes utilizar un ODBC (y cualquier otra dependencia, por ejemplo clientes de base de datos) de 32 bits.

Probablemente el ejecutable de tu aplicación, compilada con Delphi, sean de 64 bits, por lo que para depurar la aplicación necesitarías una conexión de 64 bits.

En resumen, para resolver tu problema particular, **instala el driver ODBC de 32 bits de MySQL y trabaja sobre él**.

Esto puede ser confuso cuando inicias, pero es lo habitual, ya que las bibliotecas dinámicas (por ejemplo DLL's) que se cargan en una aplicación compartirán el mismo espacio de memoria, se ejecutarán dentro del mismo proceso y pueden compartir otros recursos a nivel de sistema operativo, estas deben ser de la misma arquitectura que el ejecutable principal. (ODBC y los clientes de base de datos terminan siendo dll's que se cargan dentro de tu proceso).

Mi aseveración que el IDE de Delphi es una aplicación de 32 bits puede llegar a cambiar en futuras versiones de Delphi, por lo que invito a los lectores del futuro a asegurarse de la arquitectura de su IDE antes de dar por cierto lo dicho a inicios del 2021.

Comment: probe con ambos ODBC de 32 bits y ODBC de 64 bits.
tal vez si me instalo team viewer... me puedas ayudar, por favor..!!